# Unable to install new build in xcode

Tags: flutter, xcode

I am trying to run new build of my app in xcode, but getting an error

Unable to install /Users/elenaepstejn/Documents/GitHub/samples/changers/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app on BF2DD63C-7D56-42F1-993D-63F5CF7A1CA5. This is sometimes caused by a malformed plist file:
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSMachErrorDomain, code=-308):
The operation couldn’t be completed. (Mach error -308 - (ipc/mig) server died)
Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun simctl install BF2DD63C-7D56-42F1-993D-63F5CF7A1CA5 /Users/elenaepstejn/Documents/GitHub/samples/changers/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro.

Does anyone know how to fix that? I would be very thankful.